# Export default {} in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, export

I'm new to react native and I am trying to understand the export function.

I've seen codes in which the end of the code says `export default {}`. But what does this do? Export an object that's empty?

For example, in this code, is this doing anything relevant?:

```
export const generateRGB = () => {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    return { r, g, b }
};

export const mutateRGB = ({ r, g, b }) => {
    const newR = r + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10;
    const newG = g + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10;
    const newB = b + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10;
    return { r: newR, g: newG, b: newB }
};
  
export default {};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are linter rules that require a default export, even if there are named exports in the module. This may attempt to satisfy that.

Interestingly, general sentiment seems to be swinging AGAINST default exports, and I know I prefer not to use them. Blog post with more info on that (not mine): https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/stop-using-default-exports-javascript-module/